# Get destination type from Automapper.Mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have used Automapper for some time now, and it works very neat.
I have the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.MyModel,Entities.MyEntity>();
```

Is there any way, any method that, provided `typeof(Models.MyModel)` will return `typeof(Entities.MyEntity)` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get all the registered `TypeMap`s (Automapper's type for storing source-destination type pairs and other mapping related information) with the `Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps()` method.

Using the typemaps you can search for you source type:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Models.MyModel, Entities.MyEntity>();
    var destination = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps()
                            .First(t => t.SourceType == typeof(Models.MyModel));
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof (Entities.MyEntity), destination.DestinationType);
}
```

Comment: In the current version GetAllTypeMaps method on mapper is depricated and it is moved to MapperConfiguration.

Comment: seems to be completely gone now or am I missing something?